# How to use pg_restore in database with different postgis installation (postgis schema location)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgis, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have database1 where postgis is installed in the public schema. 
And database2 where postgis is located in a schema called postgis.

When I dump database1.schema1, schema1.table1 references its geom column as public.geometry.

Therefore pg_restore throws "schema public does not exists" error
because schema1.table1 has public.geometry column and the schema does not exists nor is postgis installed in that schema.

How can I make a clean pg_dump without having schema qualified geometry columns?

The database2 search_path points to the schema postgis. 
I am using PostgresSQL 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. Install PostGIS in the same schema in both databases. That shouldn't be a problem in the new database.

The alternative would be to manually edit the dump file, which is tedious and error prone.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just to be sure, can I move postgis to public in the new database, restore the data then move postgis back where it was? I'm unsure whether moving postgis around in a database is actually safe even though the how-to is on postgis.net

Comment: If `postgis.control` contains `relocatable = true`, you can move it to another schema using `ALTER EXTENSION` without any problem.

Comment: I don't have acess to the server itself. "update pg_extension set extrelocatable = True where extname = 'postgis'" does the same?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked, and PostGIS is not relocatable. So the simple solution is not possible.

Comment: On postgis.net they explain how to relocate it. Doesn't it work? https://www.postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/

Comment: That is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

As stated By Laurenz, you must install PostGIS in the same schema in both databases.

Afterward, it is possible to migrate postgis extensions doing the following : https://www.postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/

The migration can be done in an intermediate DB if need be.